# How to include empty values using in a query to create relationship between column and row

Tags: sql-server, string-aggregation

I have a query who returns the next results

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| idPeriodo | codigo | valor |
+-----------+--------+-------+
|     1     |   7    |  1000 |
|     1     |   8    |  1000 | 
|     1     |   9    |  1000 | 
|     2     |   7    |  1000 | 
|     2     |   8    |  1000 | 
|     3     |   7    |  1000 | 
|     3     |   9    |  1000 |  
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

I need to organize the query because I'm creating a text plain file with the results, so in the first row I need to put each "codigo" split by tab, something like this.

```
--This is the first row, is like a head
    7   8   9
```

Afther this, I need to put the column "valor" associated with its respective codigo and idPeriodo. The final result must be something like this:

```
    7       8       9
1   1000    1000    1000
2   1000    1000    
3   1000            1000
```

Now I have two queries, the first one is to obtain the first row(head with codigo values) and second one I'm doing a query to obtain all values from column "valor" grouped by idPeriodo.
These are my queries looks like.

```
-------Query to return head(codigo values)---------------
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(conjunto.codigo, central.confterm_id) as codigo_central 
FROM   mantenimiento_central_termica mantenimiento 
JOIN   configuracion_central_termica central 
ON     central.confterm_id = mantenimiento.confterm_id 
JOIN   conjunto_centrales conjunto
ON     central.id_conjuntocentral = conjunto.id

-------Query to return valor grouped by idPeriodo---------------
SELECT id_periodo , 
       valor_mantenimiento = string_agg(valor_mantenimiento, CHAR(9))
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY codigo_central)
FROM(
SELECT CONCAT(conjunto.codigo, central.confterm_id) as codigo_central, 
       per_id                          AS id_periodo , 
       mantenimcentraltermica_potencia AS valor_mantenimiento 
FROM   mantenimiento_central_termica mantenimiento 
JOIN   configuracion_central_termica central 
ON     central.confterm_id = mantenimiento.confterm_id 
JOIN   conjunto_centrales conjunto
ON     central.id_conjuntocentral = conjunto.id
WHERE  cas_id = 2) main_thermal
GROUP BY id_periodo
```

The problem I have is the second query returns only the values from column valor who is not null and when I'm going to split the first query with the second one I obtain something like this:

```
    7       8       9
1   1000    1000    1000
2   1000    1000    
3   1000    2000    --The error is here, because the 2000 value must be in the third column, with the 9(codigo) value.
```

I need the query put a blank space when find a null valor in a relation between codigo and idPeriodo.

How Can i do that ?

Comment: You must use LEFT JOIN instead of simple (inner) one, and COALESCE for to convert NULL to empty string (or space char) for the left records where right value not exists.

Comment: I think you're going to have use a `PIVOT` also? Also, could you please tag the question with your version of SQL Server - it can be very important for the answer. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided in stackoverflow.
This is the link to the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59737671/3865734